# emacs python mode preferences

Tags: python, emacs

I 'm just starting to use Python, but I'm a very experienced emacs user. I'd trying to decide between python.el and python-mode.el (or any other equivalent mode people can suggest).

Currently I'm leaning strongly towards python-mode.el, mainly because it has a useful "indent-region" method...

However, there's a couple of features of C-mode that I seem to lack in both modes which is go to the next/previous function (c-beginning-of-defun) (this differs from py-goto-block-up in that 1) there is no py-goto-block-down, and 2) you can use c-b.... to scroll up through multiple functions, but the py-.. only goes out levels)

Also, since C has braces, etc, it's easy to find the beginning/end of a current section. py-goto-block-up gives me the beginning of a block, but there is no equivalent for the end of the block...

thanks

Comment: You can indent Python blocks rigidly with python.el under Emacs 23.2 by simply selecting the block text and then typing C-c < (python-shift-left) or C-c > (python-shift-right) if that is what appeals to you about indent-region under python-mode.el

Comment: The question is "Is there a better python mode? or how can I do these things in the existing python modes?"

Answer (score 4):

There are `C-M-a` and `C-M-e` in python-mode. They go to start and end, respectively, of the current def or class. They're mapped to `beginning-of-defun` and `end-of-defun` by default.

There's also `C-c C-u`, which is mapped to `python-beginning-of-block`. My python-mode doesn't map `python-end-of-block` by default, but it's there too.

Comment: yes, but they only work for top level stuctures, like def and class...  you can't use them for finding the end of a forloop...

Comment: Ah, for some reason I thought you already had `python-[beginning|end]-of-block`. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I find pdbtrack (part of python-mode.el) invaluable

Answer (score 0):

current python-mode.el comes with a lot of finer grained commands resp.
to block, statement, expression, partial-expression, class, def, line

with attributes of beg/end/copy/delete/execute

get it at

https://launchpad.net/python-mode

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget there are two `python.el` files.  One is the "old" one in Emacs now, and [the other](https://github.com/fgallina/python.el/) is by fgallina and will be in Emacs 24.2 when it's released.  I'm not qualified to say if the new one is better than `python-mode.el`.